# Can I edit my comments on the Stack Overflow blog?

Tags: support, comments, edits, blog

I posted a comment on [What senior developers can learn from beginners](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/19/what-senior-developers-can-learn-from-beginners/?unapproved=498429&moderation-hash=be236945ea224b1e374edb7fd6f766cc#comment-498429) on the Stack Overflow blog. When I wrote my comment, I failed to realize that `<cctype>` and `<ctype.h>` would each be converted into the empty string, presumably because they are parsed as HTML tags.

I did not attempt to post a block of code in my comment, and I'm not asking how to do something like that. I just mentioned those headers within prose.

**Is there a way for me to edit that blog comment?** Is the best I can do to reply to it, indicating the mistake? I don't see a way to edit and I'm guessing editing may not be supported. But I may be missing something.

When I first looked for a way to edit my post (and posted this question), my comment on the blog is still awaiting moderation. Since then, it was approved. The interface doesn't appear much different to me, so I think that doesn't make a difference as far as whether or not editing is possible or how it is done.

(It's the Stack *Overflow* blog, and the post is about programming, but the blog is also used for communications about SE that aren't SO-specific as well. So I figured MSE was preferred to MSO for this question.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not sure on the state of plugins for editing (I don't think edit is an option right now), but I went ahead and made the edit for you.

```
&lt;cctype&gt; and &lt;ctype.h&gt;
```

... passed through just fine (as expected).